# Android studio custom language support

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-plugin

I have the need to add the support for a DSL(domain-specific language) to the android studio. What I want to achieve is an extension recognized and syntax highlighting and at the moment of the creation of the new project set up the necessary files for the environment.
Looking around the web I haven't found a good way to do this. I have thought about some solutions but I can't figure out if these are realizable.
Solution 1:
Modify the standard Android project wizard maybe adding a checkbox that set up the environment for the type of language like the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRoJH.jpg

I think this is probably unachievable.

Solution 2:
Once I created my default Android project add in the right mouse button click menu an option to set up the environment for the project.

Solution 3: 
Create a custom wizard project setup just for my language.

I don't know if it's possible to do a similar thing in Android Studio. Any help is appreciated

Comment: #1 is likely to be impractical. #2 and #3 are more promising. I would focus on seeing how to do what you want in IntelliJ IDEA (the foundation for Android Studio), then see whether that requires tweaks to work with Android Studio.

Comment: Solution 2 is definitely possible and easiest to implement. As far as I know Android Studio does not support any customization of the project wizard, so I don't think 1 or 3 are possible.